# R: use aggregate for function with matrix arguments

Tags: r

I would like to use the mutlivariate energy test for each class as in the following example:

```
require(energy)
aggregate(formula = .~Species, FUN = function(x, R) (mvnorm.etest(as.matrix(x), R = R)$p.value), data = iris, R = 999)
```

However, there is an error:

```
Error in P %*% diag(1/sqrt(lambda)) : non-conformable arguments
```

Is there any way out to do this in one shot?

Thanks for any help towards this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach I came up with without using aggregate:

```
lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(x) mvnorm.etest(x[, -5], 999))
$setosa

    Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters

data:  x, sample size 50, dimension 4, replicates 999
E-statistic = 1.2034, p-value = 0.03604


$versicolor

    Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters

data:  x, sample size 50, dimension 4, replicates 999
E-statistic = 1.084, p-value = 0.1502


$virginica

    Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters

data:  x, sample size 50, dimension 4, replicates 999
E-statistic = 1.0219, p-value = 0.3233
```

Here is another approach I have come up with using `dplyr` and `broom` package's `tidy` function that organizes results into a data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(tidy(mvnorm.etest(select(., -Species), 999)))

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: Species [3]

     Species statistic    p.value                                                      method
      <fctr>     <dbl>      <dbl>                                                      <fctr>
1     setosa  1.203397 0.03303303 Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters
2 versicolor  1.083996 0.16916917 Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters
3  virginica  1.021852 0.31431431 Energy test of multivariate normality: estimated parameters
```

Hope this helps. If you must use aggregate, I can figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Thamks! I knew about (and was using) the lapply, not about dplyr. But I would also like to use aggregate in order to better understand how to get it to work for matrix like arguments. So, any help on that would also be very appreciated.